# Кодировка с XML текста

Tags: c#, xml

Здравствуйте. Вопрос по кодировке XML текста.

Делаю запрос, откуда получаю ответ в виде XML текста. Сам текст:

```
<mission> 
    <id>2</id> 
    <x>120</x> 
    <y>180</y> 
    <missionText>Барыжить зубными щетками</missionText> 
</mission> 
<mission>
```

Вытаскиваю  текст между  missionText и вывожу в текст бокс, мне выдает непонятные каракули. Пробовал раскодировать таким кодом:

```
textBox3.Text = Uri.UnescapeDataString(missionText);
```

Но толку от этого не стало. Может, кто-то может с этим помочь? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В какой кодировке приходит ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `Encoding.UTF8`

вот [пример](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/CSharp/System.Text/Encoding/C_Encoding_UTF8.htm)

Comment: Компилятор ругается.

У меня это в стринг переменой `string missionText  = null;`


>Ошибка 1 Невызываемый член "System.Text.Encoding.UTF8" не может использоваться как метод. C:\Users\Толян\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ходки\Ходки\Form1.cs 130 50 Ходки,

Comment: Спасибо все уже разобрался !)была кодировка в UTF -8 в гет запросе это изменил и теперь перекодировать нечего не нужно вот код 

        private string get(string s)
        {


            try
            {
                WebRequest reguest = WebRequest.Create(s);
                return new StreamReader(reguest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();//изменил эту строчку 

            }
            catch { return "0"; }

Comment: Вы молодец. Получается, я верно ответил на  ваш вопрос?